# Configuring Apache for localhost

Tags: linux, apache

I am new to Linux and Apache. I have tried to configure Apache2 to serve a website I develop on my local Linux Mint machine. I have not attepted to use PHP yet.

In spite of trying to follow all the instructions, I still got a 404 Not Found or 403 Forbidden.

The name of the directory that holds the website is Web and has permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 15 18:46 Web
```

I also tried my own user group with no luck. All files inside Web have the usual r-x or r-- permissions for both Group and Others.

/etc/hosts is

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf is

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/Web.conf is

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

    ServerName Web

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /xxx/xxxx

</VirtualHost>
```

Note that /xxx is my custom partion on my local machine and xxxx is a directory in this partion.

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled is

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 May 23 13:04 Web.conf -> ../sites-available/Web.conf
```

Finally, the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf included this

```
<Directory /xxx/xxxx/Web/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I finally did get localhost to work, but it was not as above. I simply made a link to the directory Web in /var/www/html.

/var/www/html is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11321 Apr 14 15:11 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    17 May 22 16:54 Web -> /xxx/xxxx/Web
```

This worked with no chances in apache2.conf and I did not have to enable the site (make a link with a2ensite).

The url

```
localhost/Web
```

now works with no errors.

It works, but it can not be the right way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you reloaded the Apache config or restarted the server after changing its config? On Ubuntu/Debian, it could be done using `sudo service apache2 reload`. Try reloading it and edit your answer appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I have done this every time I have made a chance, either sudo service apache2 reload or sudo service apache2 restart.

Comment: What do logs say?

Comment: The error log in /var/log/apache2 only reports each time I reload Apache. The access log typically only says this: `localhost:80 127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2017:15:43:52 +0200] "GET /Web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.` I don't know how to get more information out of the logs.

Comment: I have seen that this post has had a number of hits. Therefore I think it is necessary (over 2 years later) to clarify the issue.  If you host **multiple** localhost websites, add a link to each one in /var/www/html. In addition, you need to add folder rights in apache2.conf. I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

`/xxx/xxxx` also needs to be readable by `www-data` in order to work as document root. You'll also need the permissions defined in a directory block.

```
<Directory /xxx/xxxx/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Or set your `DocumentRoot /xxx/xxxx/Web`

Comment: I set  `DocumentRoot /xxx/xxxx/Web ` and have `<Directory /data/Gallery/Web/> ... </Directory>`, set permissions on Web as `drwxr-xr-x  4 me www-data   4096 May 15 18:46 Web` (me is the owner) ,  did a `sudo service apache2 reload` and emptied the browser cache. With url `localhost/Web` I still got a 404 Not Found.

Comment: The `/data/Gallery/Web/` is of course what I called `/xxx/xxxx/Web/`. I used the xxx's to make things clearer. Thank you anyway for the answer.